# Can you make a "Test Suite" in Pytest like you can do in Nose?

Tags: python, pytest

Is it possible to programmatically build up a list of tests to run in pytest?

In Nose, you can write a python script to select the tests that you want to run. This is called a test suite.

For example:

```
class TestFoo(TestCase):
    ...

class TestBar(TestCase):
    ...


tests = []

if sys.argv[1] == 'foo':
    tests.append(TestFoo)
elif sys.argv[1] == 'bar':
    tests.append(TestBar)
else:
    tests.append(TestFoo)
    tests.append(TestBar)


tests = [
    TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(test)
    for test in tests 
]
suite = LazySuite(tests)

run(suite=suite)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pytest` has its own ways of doing this, arguably with less boilerplate! You could map your examples to using pytest command line arguments:

- `python tests.py foo` to `pytest -k Foo`, which greps for `Foo` in function names;
- `python tests.py bar` to `pytest -k Bar`, obviously
- `python tests.py thingummywut` to simply `pytest`

That, however, depends on a naming convention that all `foo`-related tests include `Foo` in their name. You can also decorate test functions (or classes, if you're into that style) with marks, such as `@pytest.mark.foo`, and then call all of those with `pytest -m foo`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a public hook [`pytest_collection_modify_items`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=hooks#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) which could be used to similar effect. It will be called after collection has been performed, and the user may filter or re-order the items in-place.

```
# in conftest.py

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    keep = []
    for item in items:
        if <something> ... :
            keep.append(item)
    items[:] = keep
```